# Is it possible to make an anonymous class inherit another class?

Tags: c#, anonymous-class

This is a long shot, but I have a funny coding situation where I want the ability to create anonymous classes on the fly, yet be able to pass them as a parameter to a method that is expecting an interface or subclass.  In other words, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
public class MyBase { ... }

public void Foo(MyBase something)
{
  ...
}

...
var q = db.SomeTable.Select(t =>
        new : MyBase // yeah, I know I can't do this...
        {
          t.Field1,
          t.Field2,
        });
foreach (var item in q)
  Foo(item);
```

Is there any way to do this other than using a named class?

Comment: You *could* use `dynamic` as parameter type instead of `MyBase` but I would strongly suggest not doing that for anything that has even the remote chance of being called from more than one place.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No. Anonymous types always implicitly derive from `object`, and never implement any interfaces.

From section 7.6.10.6 of the C# 5 specificiation:

> An anonymous object initializer declares an anonymous type and returns an instance of that type. An anonymous type is a nameless class type that inherits directly from `object`.

So if you want a different base class *or* you want to implement an interface, you need a named type.

Comment: Spookily I was thinking about this earlier except with interfaces. Maybe even at the time this question was asked... :)

Answer (score 8):

No. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

*Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object.*

To solve your problem, just replace the anonymous type with normal class...

Answer (score 2):

Cannot extend an anonymous but you could declare your method to accept a dynamic parameter if you really need this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer:
You could use a C# proxy class. There are several tools that can proxy classes. For example Moqs. https://github.com/moq/moq4